# How to set the returning value of a function into a variable in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have this function in Postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verificar2 (rooms INT[], fecha_I DATE, fecha_F DATE) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $verificar_Fechas$
DECLARE
    reg INT;
    size int := array_length(rooms,1); --Get the size of the array to search one by one
    x int; --for counting the reservations available
BEGIN
    FOR reg IN 1..size
    loop
        SELECT count(*) INTO x
        FROM 
            reservacion r 
            INNER JOIN rh ON (r.num_reservacion=rh.num_reservacion)
            INNER JOIN habitacion h ON (h.num_habitacion=rh.num_habitacion)
        where   h.num_habitacion=rooms[reg]
            and not 
            (fecha_F BETWEEN r.fecha_entrada AND r.fecha_salida
            or
            fecha_I BETWEEN r.fecha_entrada AND r.fecha_salida
            or
            fecha_I < r.fecha_Entrada and fecha_F > r.fecha_salida
            );

        IF x = 0 Then
          return false;
        ELSE
          return true;
        END IF;
    end loop;
END;
$verificar_Fechas$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I have another function with the following variable
validReservations BOOLEAN;

I need to set the returning value of the first function to the variable and I tried doing

```
validR := verificar2 (rooms, fecha_entrada, fecha_salida);
```

But it didn't work and I need that to make a validation. Can you help me?

Comment: where did you try doing it? in other function? give a code then

Comment: "*but it didn't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with SELECT INTO:

```
SELECT * INTO validReservations FROM verificar2 (rooms, fecha_entrada, fecha_salida);
```

This will "SELECT" the return value into your variable.